# SimpleXML import into PHP. Do I need to close file?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm importing data into a php array from an xml file using SimpleXML.

I'm using the `simplexml_load_file` function, but once i've got the data I need, do I need to close the file or similar to clear the memory?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you don't need to do anything with the file. [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) will close the file internally after it has read the content.

If you take a look at the source code for `simplexml_load_file`, you'll see that it is calling  the `C` function `xmlReadFile()` form xmllib2, which in turn will close the file after reading.

```
PHP_FUNCTION(simplexml_load_file)
{
    php_sxe_object *sxe;
    char           *filename;
    int             filename_len;
    xmlDocPtr       docp;
    char           *ns = NULL;
    int             ns_len = 0;
    long            options = 0;
    zend_class_entry *ce= sxe_class_entry;
    zend_bool       isprefix = 0;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s|C!lsb", &filename, &filename_len, &ce, &options, &ns, &ns_len, &isprefix) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    docp = xmlReadFile(filename, NULL, options);  <--- reading the file
```

Comment: Thanks again MrCode, that's a great help :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean along the lines of `fopen()` and `fclose()` then no.. the file is parsed and turned into an object by simplexml, if you want to be really pedantic you could unset the object after you're finished with it.

Comment: Thanks Dale, that helps a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to close the file as it is automatically closed when read the whole file. However if you are asking because you are running out of server memory, you should take a look at the server logs where the memory is most consumed and free it.

`simplexml_load_file` is meant to make life simple :)